# Python - How to use list comprehension to populate a named tuples values

Tags: python, list, collections, namedtuple

I have the following class which creates a deck of cards:

```
import collections


Card = collections.namedtuple('Card', ['rank', 'suit', 'value'])


class FrenchDeck:
    ranks = [str(n) for n in range(2, 11)] + list('JQKA')
    suits = 'spades clubs hearts diamonds'.split()
    card_value = [str(n + 1) for n in range(len(ranks))]

    def __init__(self):
        self._cards = [Card(rank, suit, value)
                       for suit in self.suits
                       for rank in self.ranks
                       for value in self.card_value
                       ]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._cards)

    def __getitem__(self, position):
        return self._cards[position]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    FrenchDeck()
```

I have added the `value` value to Card in order to assign a value to each card, like so:

```
Card(rank='2', suit='spades', value='1')
Card(rank='2', suit='spades', value='2')
Card(rank='2', suit='spades', value='3')
Card(rank='2', suit='spades', value='4')
Card(rank='2', suit='spades', value='5')
Card(rank='2', suit='spades', value='6')
Card(rank='2', suit='spades', value='7')
Card(rank='2', suit='spades', value='8')
Card(rank='2', suit='spades', value='9')
Card(rank='2', suit='spades', value='10')
Card(rank='2', suit='spades', value='11')
Card(rank='2', suit='spades', value='12')
Card(rank='2', suit='spades', value='13')
```

It is creating 13 items for each rank for each suit. I understand why this is happening however I am struggling add the value to each rank in a suit like so:

```
Card(rank='2', suit='spades', value='1')
Card(rank='3', suit='spades', value='2')
Card(rank='4', suit='spades', value='3')
Card(rank='5', suit='spades', value='4')
Card(rank='6', suit='spades', value='5')
Card(rank='7', suit='spades', value='6')
Card(rank='8', suit='spades', value='7')
Card(rank='9', suit='spades', value='8')
Card(rank='10', suit='spades', value='9')
Card(rank='J', suit='spades', value='10')
Card(rank='K', suit='spades', value='11')
Card(rank='Q', suit='spades', value='12')
Card(rank='A', suit='spades', value='13')
```

Any idea how to go about achieve this?

Comment: `value` is not an independent attribute of a `Card`; it is a function of the rank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually do not nest your lists-iteration as you think you do.

Changing from

```
def __init__(self):
    self._cards = [Card(rank, suit, value)
                   for suit in self.suits
                   for rank in self.ranks
                   for value in self.card_value
                   ]
```

to

```
def __init__(self):
    self._cards = [Card(rank, suit, value)
                   for suit in self.suits
                   for rank, value in zip(self.ranks,\
                                          self.card_value)
                   ]
```

accomplishes what you want. Note that this is equivalent to:

```
def __init__(self):
    self._cards = []
    for suit in self.suits:
        for rank, value in zip(self.ranks, self.card_value):            
            self._cards+=[Card(rank, suit, value)]
```

Furthermore, as said by chepner, or operationalized by Jérémy,

> `value` is not an independent attribute of a `Card`; it is a function of the `rank`.

Which means that you could iter over `value` of `self.card_value` for each element of `self.suits`, and then get the corresponding `rank` based on the `value` you work on.

#### more details

following your comment/question

You define `ranks` as

```
ranks = [str(n) for n in range(2, 11)] + list('JQKA')
```

and then, based on `ranks`, you define `card_value` as follows

```
card_value = [str(n + 1) for n in range(len(ranks))]
```

Which clearly shows the dependence between the two objects: each element of the list `card_value`, is/has a direct transformation/correspondance of/with each element of the list `ranks`.

*just for free* I would have put an `s` to the pointer's name `self.card_value` for the sake of clarity. i.e. `self.card_values`

Comment: Are you able to go into a bit more detail regarding this: "value is not an independent attribute of a Card; it is a function of the rank."

Comment: @Lewis909. See details. More details or clear enough ?

Comment: that's perfect thanks. And because I wanted to add both `rank` and `value` to each item in `suit` that is why`zip` is used.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip regard the extra `s`, it has been added.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of loop over ranks, access directly by index work.

```
    self._cards = [Card(self.ranks[int(value) - 1], suit, value)
                   for suit in self.suits
                   for value in self.card_value
                   ]
```